# ASM .com won't run

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I found this sample tutorial [The clueless guide to Hello World in nasm](http://home.comcast.net/~fbkotler/clueless.html) about basic ASM, when I compile it, everyting goes just fine!!! Great, but when I run it I get this message:

> This version of hi.com is not compatible with the version of Windows you are running

This happens on Windows 7 x64 (Which i was told would run fine) with this code

```
org 100h
mov dx,msg
mov ah,9
int 21h
mov ah,4Ch
int 21h
msg db 'Hello, World!',0Dh,0Ah,'$'
```

Comment: It would be great if someone cant point me to some 32 bit code tutos

Comment: This is very old and not sure if it will help, but this is assembly for win32, http://win32assembly.online.fr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought you couldn't get 16 bit programs to run in 64 bit windows at all.  Try [DOSBOX](http://www.dosbox.com/)

Answer (score 1):

That looks like 16bit DOS code and 16bit code is not  compatible anymore with Vista and above (at least Win7). Perhaps you can find a tutorial that creates a 32 bit or 64 bit PE image. It will only be an executable (.exe) and not a .com file.